# Set elements added to List, then mess

Tags: java, list, collections, set

So basically I have this constructor for the class `League`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class League {

    private String name;
    private List<Team> teamList;

    public League(String name) {        
        List<String> teamNames = new LinkedList<String>(Company.teamList);
        Collections.shuffle(teamNames);
        teamNames.subList(0, 5);

        for(int i = 0; i < teamNames.size(); i++){
            teamList.add(new Team(teamNames.get(i)));
        }
}
}
```

The class `Company` happens to have a `Set` called `teamList`.
When I call on `System.out.println(teamNames.get(i))` it shows me the content so obviously the elements of the set are there, however when I try to create a new `Team` object based on the elements of the list of Strings, it gives me a `NullPointerException`. **I don't know why is that? Help?**

Here is the code for the Team class in case you need it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Team {

    protected Map<Integer, Player> teamPlayerMap;
    private String teamName;

    public Team(String name) {
        teamPlayerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Player>();
        teamName = name;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please try to come up with a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What does the stacktrace tell you?

Comment: Therre is no way `new Team(null)` can throw a nullpointerexception. Please show us more code to be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
private List<Team> teamList;

public League(String name) {        
    // etc...

    for(int i = 0; i < teamNames.size(); i++) {
        teamList.add(new Team(teamNames.get(i))); // This will throw!
    }
}
```

You need to create an instance of a class that implements `List<Team>` and assign it to `teamList`. You haven't done this so it will throw a `NullPointerException` when you call `teamList.add(...)`.

The fix is to write this instead:

```
private List<Team> teamList = new ArrayList<Team>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize teamList:

```
private List<Team> teamList = new ArrayList<Team>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because you not create instance of teamList I think.